# How do i change this into JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, foreach

How can I send multiple values to be picked up like this using JSON?

```
foreach($_POST['listItem'] as $key => $values){

    list($eventDate, $eventTitle) = $values;

}
```

At the moment the values are sent as follows. But this doesn't appear to work properly as it is only sending some of the string. I also can't figure out where/how to send the caltitle value.

This is sending me crazy. Any help would be great.

```
var txt = $("#listbox");

            var caltitle = copiedEventObject.title

            var dtstart = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(copiedEventObject.start, 'yyyyMMdd');

            var txt = $('#listbox');     
            txt.append("<li class ='listItem'> " + dtstart + "</li>")

            // remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();           

        }
    });


        $('#calendarform').submit(function(e) {
            var form = $(this);
            var listItems = $('.listItem'); 
            listItems.each(function(index){   //For each event do this:
                var listItem = $(this);
                    $("<input type='hidden'/>").val(listItem.text()).appendTo(form).attr('name', 'listItem[' + index + ']');
                });

            //Get text information from elements

        });
```

EDIT:

(using JSON)

```
  $('#calendarform').submit(function(e) {
            var form = $(this);

            var going_to_be_json = [];
            list.each(function(i, item) {
              going_to_be_json.push({
                 'id':'test',
                 'title': 'test'
              });
            });

            $('#stuff').val( JSON.stringify(going_to_be_json) );

     });
```

Comment: What the `$values` variable in foreach looks like? Is it an array or a string? What should the jQuery code help us with?

Comment: Well, im trying to make an array. Basically i have a date  and a title that I need to get into the foreach on the action page. I need to modify the hidden input to get them both across and i can't work it out.

Comment: no need to use ``index`` variable on the ``.attr('name', 'listItem[]');``. try like this.

Comment: ok, i have updated that. and im getting the first value across. But im not sure where i put into that the array for the 'caltitle' to go?

Comment: @Gokhan Ozturk Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare the data into an array of objects then convert that array to JSON using JSON.stringify() and set the hidden form value to said string (or use XHR to submit it to the server).

Here is a very limited example of how to prepare the data:

```
var going_to_be_json = [];
list.each(function(i, item) {
  going_to_be_json.push({
     'id':item.id,
     'title': item.title,
     'date': (new Date()).now()
  });
});
hidden_form_element.val( JSON.stringify(going_to_be_json) );
```

and on the server

```
<?php
$json_data_string = $_POST['hidden_form_field_containing_json_data']; // sanitize however
$array_data = json_decode($json_data_string);
```

More can be ready about JSON (Javascript Object Notation) from [json.org](http://www.json.org/) and [the Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info) (although the tag wiki just shows you more examples and links)

it seems you needed a little more direction. I was hoping you wouldn't just copy and paste what I had and you would read and attempt to understand what it is doing....

```
   $('#calendarform').submit(function(e) {
        var form = $(this),
            listItems = $('.listItem'),
            data = [],
            hidden = $('<input />'); // create a hidden field for the form.
                                    // or just select the hidden form element from the page
        hidden[0].type = 'hidden'; // set the type
        hidden[0].name = 'some_name_for_php_to_recognize'; // and name

        listItems.each(function(i,el){ 
             data.push({'index': i, 'text': $(el).text()});
        });

        hidden.val(JSON.stringify(data));
        $(this).append(hidden); // not needed if the hidden element is already in the DOM

    });
```

Comment: Dont seem to be able to get it to send anything? Im trying to just send 'id:'test',

Comment: how are you submitting the data?

Comment: I have edited the question with the code. the hidden field in the form has an id of 'stuff'

Comment: that is because `list` was an arbitrary value you were not supposed to use.

Comment: Sorry, Thanks for all your help. I did try and change list to listItems but that didn't help either. I'm fairly new with javascript/jquery so thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Hey @rlemon. I am still having no luck with this code. It isn't even sending a value in the post. I am trying to just echo out a value from the post and cant get that to work. I suck with javascript and i'm probably missing something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

send it with jQuery Post or Get method and fetch it by php you can send multiple values
use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)